# Syntax Error in manage.py while executing process_tasks

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to execute some background apps in Django 2.2 but every time I call python3 manage.py process_tasks it raise syntax error other commands like run server, migrate, ... works fine only for process_tasks it raises this error
even when I comment on all background task codes

```
File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It for sure is issue with you virtual environment  or  django is not  installed properly.

Comment: That would give a syntax error if you were running **Python 2**. It really shouldn't give an error if you are really running `python3 manage.py`.

Comment: @uglyCoder i re-installed virtualenv problem solved thanks.